# While loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop

Could anyone please explain to me why my while loop won't end when i enter character 'Q'? It kept on looping even though i set my boolean value to false when the user enter 'Q', it supposed to end after that scanf for `char input`.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

int main(void) {
    char input;
    char output;
    bool tf = true;

    printf("Welcome to the Coder!\n");

    while (tf) {
        printf("Choose Input (H,A,B,Q) : ");
        scanf_s(" %c\n", &input);

        if (input == 'Q') {
            tf = false;
        }
        else {
            printf("Choose Output (H,A,B) : ");
            scanf_s(" %c\n", &output);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you press enter after typing Q?

Comment: yet another scanf issue?

Comment: yes i did press enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the weird case of `scanf_s`. Accord to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), you read single characters using this syntax:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &input, 1);
```

Remove the `\n` from `scanf_s` and add the 1 parameter so it knows to read only 1 character.

Comment: this solved the problem thanks. I don't really need the \n after %c

Answer (score 3):

I am suspecting that you are entering small letter q on your console:

I would suggest you to change your code to:

```
if (input == 'Q' || input == 'q') {
    tf = false;
}
```

Comment: Or for that matter, `#include <ctype.h>` and `if(toupper(input) == 'Q')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add if

```
(input == 'Q' || input == 'q')
```

Also why did you add `typedef int bool;`? This was unneeded.

I replace `scanf_s` to `scanf` because my compiler doesn't recognize it(accidentally solving problem.

because it is better. When I compile this there was no errors.

Compiled - > [Compiled Code](http://ideone.com/3QxqS0)